# I cannot install vmware tools

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I'm using VMWare Workstation 14 with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. When I go into Player>Manage and attempt to click "Install VMWare Tools" I am unable to. It is faded out as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525), there are some dependencies, have you isntalled `gcc` `binutils` `make` and `linux-headers-generic`

Comment: Rather than run the specific VMware tools installer and compilation rules, you may wish to instead install `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop`.  Both of these packages are open-source packages that are available in the repositories, and work on their own without having to worry about running VMware's installation toolkit.  (It installs build dependencies as well for the Desktop toolkit sets)

Comment: I'm not sure if installing open-vm-tools worked because I can't get the fullscreen to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1: Shut down your virtual machine

2: Right-click on the Virtual Machine -> Settings...

OR

VM (menu) -> Settings... [VMWare Workstation]

3: Go to `CD/DVD (SATA)` under the Hardware section -> Choose Connection as `Use physical drive:` option and keep it `Auto detect`
also checkmark `Connect at power on` option.

[image: img_VMWare_tools]

(Do the same thing if you have a Floppy drive attached)

4: Restart your virtual machine, `Install VMWare Tools...` should be active